# Vein extraction using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, detection

I am using python and opencv to do some experiments on vein extraction. First I used CLAHE to do some processing to make the vein image clearer. I then tried adaptive threshold segmentation and NiBlack, but I could hardly get any useful results.

Is there any way I can get a usable vein texture image? (hopefully get the output image and code example)

Thank you all for your help!

This is my origin image:[image]

after CLAHE:
[image]

expected like this：
[image]

Comment: Can you post the code that you are trying, along with an example of end result you are expecting?

Comment: I just used CLAHE in opencv for processing (because I am a beginner), and the results I am looking for are already attached to the problem.

Comment: This is a really hard problem. I've worked on this with retinal images. You can get a long way with something like this: split the g channel -> gaussian filter -> hysteresis thresh -> blob detection. The crucial part is the preprocessing before the blob detection.

Comment: Also those original images look pretty crufty. What kind of image is this? I couldn't pick out any veins so it'd be pretty hard to design an algorithm that could.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion,i will be try the method you said.